# How to simulate negative padding in picturebox?

Tags: c#, picturebox

What possibilities are there to simulate negative padding in a picturebox in C#? I want to be able to show a cropped version of an image without actually cropping it. When "cropping" the right or bottom side it's easy just to change the size of the picturebox to hide a part of the image, but how do I get the picturebox to hide some pixels on the left or top sides without either cropping the original image or creating a new cropped version of it?

Comment: You'll have to give up on the Image property and use its Paint event instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and see if I can figure out what to do.

Comment: ..or you could put the PictureBox into a Panel and set a negative Location.

Comment: That's a very good idea and a remarkably easy solution. Thanks.